# Can I put a breakpoint in the main method when I do not know the class whose main method is invoked during startup?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jetty, osgi

I am working on a complex java application made up of thousands of jars, including spring and jetty. Is it possible to put a breakpoint in main() method? I do not know the class whose main method is used during startup. I am able to start the application on the commandline and remotely attach to it using Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA. I am also able to run the app in debug mode and make it wait till a debugger attaches to it.

The app is started thus:

```
/java -Xss512k -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:-UseCodeCacheFlushing -XX:-Tiered=path.to.log.file -XX:StackShadowPages=20  -classpath path.to.jar.file launcher.OsgiLauncher -Frobnitz path.to.Jetty94.jetty.gen.xml
```

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult to find the main method as Java doesn't support much complexity here. How is the app started?

Comment: You'll have better luck with an osgi tag. AFAIK, the `main()` method with your command line is OSGi itself, aka the `launcher.OsgiLauncher` class has it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcard method breakpoint for this (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/creating-method-breakpoints.html#d871635e20),
see the alternative creation method:
[image: wildcard method breakpoint]

Then please unset emulated checkbox in breakpoint properties, because of the bug [IDEA-173268](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-173268)